# Can't get wifi working with new network adapter

Tags: debian, networking, wifi, drivers, pci

My wifi was really slow. I decided to buy a new wifi adapter (archer t8e). It has the BCM4360 chipset. I got it said it was connected using ndiswrapper, but I wasn't able to get websites loaded. The link on [wikidev](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/TP-LINK_Archer_T8E) says it should work. What would be the steps I need to proceed to get it working?

```
⋊> ~ lspci -nn -d 14e4:                                                                          
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0] (rev 03)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Debian-wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/wl#Debian):

Add a  `non-free`  component to `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
```

Install  `linux-headers` and `broadcom-sta-dkms` packages:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') broadcom-sta-dkms
```

Unload conflicting modules:

```
 modprobe -r b44 b43 b43legacy ssb brcmsmac bcma
```

Load the `wl` module:

```
 modprobe wl
```

**Edit**

Turn off the power management:

```
iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

To make it permanent create a new file under `/etc/pm/config.d`:

```
nano /etc/pm/config.d/power_off
```

With the following contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
/sbin/iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

save and make it executable `chmod +x /etc/pm/config.d/power_off` then reboot

Comment: run`iwconfig wlan0 power off`

Comment: could you also add how to make this permanent. (with modprobe.d)